# What does ${PATH:+:${PATH}} mean?

Tags: shell, path, variable-substitution

I recently noticed the following in my cygwin profile, more precisely:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

What does it mean? Why is not just $PATH? Is this an 'if $PATH exists then add :$PATH'? My purpose is to swap the order and put the cygwin paths behind the windows path. In the past I would have

```
$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

but this confuses me. Maybe I should be doing

```
PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
```

to append the : at the end of the $PATH?

Comment: Your question title really messed with the formatting in the SE Hot Questions side bar http://i.imgur.com/g6pPmzf.png

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `:+` is a form of [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> **${parameter:+[word]}** : Use Alternative Value.
>
> If parameter is unset or
>   null, null shall be substituted; otherwise, the expansion of word (or
>   an empty string if word is omitted) shall be substituted.

In other words, if the variable `$var` is defined, `echo ${var:+foo}` will print `foo` and, if it is not, it will print the empty string.

The second `:` is nothing special. It is the character used as a separator in the list of directories in `$PATH`. So, `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"` is a shorthand way of writing:

```
if [ -z "$PATH" ]; then
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
else
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
fi
```

It's just a clever trick to avoid adding an extra `:` when `$PATH` is not set. For example:

```
$ PATH="/usr/bin"
$ PATH="/new/dir:$PATH" ## Add a directory
$ echo "$PATH"
/new/dir:/usr/bin
```

But if `PATH` is unset:

```
$ unset PATH
$ PATH="/new/dir:$PATH"
$ echo "$PATH"
/new/dir:
```

A `:` by itself adds the current directory to the `$PATH`. Using `PATH="/new/dir${PATH:+:$PATH}"` avoids this. So sure, you can use `PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"` if you want to, or you can use `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"` if you prefer. The only difference is that the former might add an extra `:`, thereby adding your current directory to your `$PATH`.

Comment: Is the extra `:` harmful?

Comment: @tac not really, it just adds the current directory to your `$PATH` (see @AndyB's [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267548/22222)). That can be a security risk in some situations (say an attacker has uploaded a destructive script to your current directory and named it `ls` or something) but in most cases, you really don't mind. In fact, some systems add the current directory to the `PATH` by default anyway.

Comment: the path is the *one* place where I'd prefer they way `csh` handles then it as an array.

Comment: This is one of the best explanations ever read on the various stack... thanks

Answer (score 11):

You're correct, it does mean 'if $PATH exists — and is not null — then add :$PATH'.

You need to check whether $PATH exists because you don't want to add the leading (or trailing) colon if $PATH is undefined. A zero-length (null) directory name in the path, as in `:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`, or `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:`, or `/usr/local/bin::/usr/bin`, means *search the current directory*.

Excerpted from `man bash`:

```
   PATH   ...
          A zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH indicates 
          the current directory.  A  null  directory name may appear as two 
          adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon.
          ...
```

That's probably not what you want to do.

The following two lines do the same thing:

```
PATH=":/bin"        # search current directory, then /bin
PATH=".:/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also useful to compare *alternative* vs *default* parameter expansion.

Using `:-` inside `${}` you get a *default* value like this:

```
${a:-xxx} returns "xxx" if a is not defined.
```

Using `:+` inside `${}` you get an *alternative* value like this:

```
${a:+xxx} returns "xxx" if a is defined.
```

So in the case of `${PATH:+${PATH}:}` it basically says if `PATH` is defined, do not use just the `PATH` value, but rather return the alternative value of `PATH:`.